# Christoffel symbol / scalar product of co- and contravarient basis vectors

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

I am currently learning about the Christoffel symbole.

Given is the following equation:

$\Gamma_{nm}^{l} = e^l \cdot \Gamma_{nm}^{k} e_k$

with $e$ being an arbitrary co-/contravariant basis vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

My approach to getting this equation would be:

$e^l \cdot \Gamma^{k}_{nm} e_k = e^l \cdot \partial_m e_n = e^l \cdot \Gamma^{l}_{nm} e_l = \Gamma_{nm}^{l}\delta_l^l \stackrel{?}{=} \Gamma_{nm}^{l}$

My question is: Can i just use $e^l \cdot e_l = \delta_l^l = 1$? In my opinion $\delta_l^l=1$ shouldn't be correct because the basis vector is part of $\mathbb{R}^3$ which would suggest:

$\delta_l^l = \sum{}_{l=1}^3 \delta_l^l =3 $

but i can't see another way of getting the result give above.

Comment: Try to start from scratch from here: https://basics.altervista.org/test/Math/tensor_calculus/all.html

Comment: Could you clarify what you are asking? I also don't know what the primes are referring to here.

Comment: @Relativisticcucumber The primes are just an indicator that I'm referring to curvelinear coordinates. I removed the dots (multiplication) from the christoffel symbol. The first equation is given in my lecture notes. To give some context: It is the beginning of a proof that the christoffel symbol is symmetric. When writing it down my prof said something along the lines of: its the same because we get $e^l * e_k = \delta_k^l$. My queqtion is, how do i get from $\Gamma_{nm}^{'l}$ to $e'^l \cdot \Gamma_{nm}^{'k} e'_k$.

Comment: @basics Thank you. I dont quite understand how the proof in section "Derivates of Vectors in the Natural Basis - Christoffel symbol" works. How does the kronecker delta act on the christoffel symbol / vice versa?

Comment: *The primes are just an indicator that I'm referring to curvelinear coordinates.* If you weren’t in curvilinear coordinates, all the Christoffel symbols would be zero, and the given equation would be $0=0$. The primes are pointless and simply make things harder to read.

Comment: @oodani you've introduced the Christoffel symbols as the components of the derivative of the vectors of the natural basis w.r.t. the coordinates, expressed in the natural basis. Then you do the dot product between the vectors of the natural basis and their dual basis that, by definition of the dual basis, gives you the Kronecker delta. (I took some freedom here to use the term *dual*, but if you need more general treatment, you could find out that I'm lying to you, or at least not telling you all the truth). You can find that definition in section "natural basis ant its dual" above

Comment: *How does the kronecker delta act on the christoffel symbol / vice versa?* Do you understand the Einstein summation convention for contractions? When you contract with a Kronecker delta, only one if the terms in the resulting sum is nonzero. The contraction has the effect of changing the index. For example, $A_i\delta^i_j=A_j$.

Comment: Do you realize that $ e^l \cdot \Gamma_{nm}^{k} e_k=\Gamma_{nm}^k(e^l\cdot e_k)$?

Comment: @Ghoster is right. Please, before going on be sure you're familiar with Einstein's convention, and pay attention to the nature of the mathematical objects (scalars, vectors or tensors of higher order). To be clear, there $e^l$, $e_k$ are vectors (find a proper way to indicate them, bold, underline, arrow,...) and $\Gamma^k_{nm}$ are scalars

Comment: and when you do that dot product you get Kronecker delta

Comment: In your second line of math, you have expressions where the index $l$ appears three times. This is not allowed. A contraction is between one upper index and one lower index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to summarize what @ghoster and @basics have said in the comments. As Ghoster points out, $$e^l\cdot \Gamma ^k_{nm}e_k = \Gamma ^k_{nm} (e^l \cdot e_k)$$ We know that, by construction, of basis vectors, this term is nonzero only when $k = l$, thus we have $$(e^l \cdot e_k) = \delta^l_k$$ giving us $$\Gamma ^k_{nm} (e^l \cdot e_k) = \Gamma ^k_{nm}\delta^l_k$$ By contraction of indices, we then have $$\Gamma ^k_{nm}\delta^l_k = \Gamma ^l_{nm}$$

I would encourage you to take @basics advice and think carefully about what each entity is (vector, scalar, tensor, etc.) when you do these manipulations. :)